# Default drop down selection only when no options selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to have a default option selected only if no other options have been selected.  My current code is.

```
<%= f.association :acquiring_editors, collection: @aquiring_editor_options, wrapper: :no_label, selected: current_user.id %>
```

However, when I do select an alternative option it always reverts to the selected above.  How do I only use the current user ID if no other option is selected?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking for here. It seems to select the current user's ID regardless.

Comment: Basically I want to have a default value selected only if no options are selected.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a default, you need an `||` condition, something that'd look like:

```
selected: @thing.acquiring_editors_id || current_user_id
```

Not sure what object this is acting on, or what field might indicate which was selected, but that's the general idea.